# How to access user login status in layout files in CakePHP3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

All I need is a very simple task but still I am unable to find a solution to this. I've tried many ways using Auth component, session component. But, please note that the solution should be feasible for CakePHP's 3.x version not older one.
I have implemented Auth Component in my AppController file and now wants to know in Layout's default.ctp file that the user is logged-in or not. With this check, I would like to implement different content on the page.

Few sample codes, I've tried so far are listed below:

```
//#1
if($this->Auth->user()){
    //DO THIS
}

//#2
//Setting $user variable in AppController and accessing it in view file.
if($user){
    //DO THIS
}
```

Few others using Session and Direct Auth Component are tried but as I understood after all study is that the new version does not support Session helper anymore.

Please confirm the ambiguity and suggest some solution to carry on the task.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you need to access it via the request object, use the below code

`$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');`

As session helper is deprecated in cakephp 3.x and also Auth is a component and can't be used in view.

So indeed you can check it like

```
$session_user = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
if(!empty($session_user)){
        // User logged in
}
else
{
    // User is not logged in
}
```